# Python Whitelist Command

Tags: python, python-3.x

Application Command raised an exception:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I want to add too that if the member webhook and guild id is in config.ini it should say this member is already in the whitelist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

```
@bot.slash_command(name="add", description="whitelist")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def whitelist(ctx, guildid: discord.Option(str, "guildid", required = True), webhook: discord.Option(str, "webhook", required = True), member: discord.Option(str, "addmember", required = True)):
        user = ctx.author
        config.read('config.ini')
        config.set('hooks', str(user), webhook)
        with open('config.ini', 'w') as f:
            config.write(f)
            await ctx.respond(f"Added <@{user}> to whitelist!")
            print(f"Added {member} to the whitelist!")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).